# Does Yeppp support finding the big.LITTLE ,Revision etc

Tags: yeppp

Does Yeppp support finding the following info:

- SoC name
- No of CPUs (Like in an Exynos 5410)
- Total no of cores
- big.LITTLE
- Revision
- Process
- Current CPU load
- Max and Min clock speed
- Current clock speed
- GPU Renderer
- GPU vendor

If yes, please tell me how. I read the documentation but I couldn't find these info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- SoC name - use `yepLibrary_GetString(YepEnumerationCpuFullName, ...)` (=> "Samsung Exynos 5410"), `yepLibrary_GetString(YepEnumerationCpuBriefName, ...)` (=> "Exynos 5410"). Yeppp! on ARM detects the SoC name by parsing syslog, which is no longer available on recent Androids.
- No of CPUs (Like in an Exynos 5410) - no
- Total no of cores - there is an undocumented method `yepLibrary_GetLogicalCoresCount`. Like with anything undocumented, there is no guarantee that it will be supported in future Yeppp! versions.
- big.LITTLE - no
- Revision - this information is available internally, but not exposed through Yeppp! interface.
- Process - no. ARM CPUID registers do not contain this information.
- Current CPU load/Max and Min clock speed/Current clock speed - no
- GPU Renderer/GPU vendor - no